# in meteor, how can I use data with subscribe and I can console it

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I use meteor+angular,I publish some data, and I has subscribe it, but when I console.log it, the result is `[]`

**this is my data in mongodb**

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.site.find()
{ "_id" : "5wGu3EcSis9GJGmkf", "name" : "cc", "age" : 12 }
{ "_id" : "jEboHgEF4Hvp5rpg7", "name" : "bob", "age" : 20 }
```

**and I do this in `server.js`**

```
  3   Meteor.publish('sitelist', function() {
  4   ┊ return CheckSite.find();
  5   });
```

**I can get something in chrome's console**

```
CheckSite.find().fetch()
[Object_id: "5wGu3EcSis9GJGmkf"age: 12name: "cc"__proto__: Object, Object_id: "jEboHgEF4Hvp5rpg7"age: 20name: "bob"__proto__: Object
```

**I subscribe it in client.js:**

```
  4   ┊ $meteor.subscribe('sitelist');
  5   ┊ console.log(CheckSite.find().fetch());
```

like this, I console it , but it just `[]` in console
Why, What can I do when I `$meteor.subscribe('sitelist')`?

Comment: Where do you define the collection `CheckSite`? In a client file, server file, or both?

Comment: I define collection in `/lib/connection.js` and code is `CheckSite = new Mongo.Collection('site')

Comment: You need to wait for the subscription to complete (for the client to download all the collection data).

Comment: I can't understant you

Comment: Nataila: if you console.log() immediately after the subscribe the data won't have been returned yet and you'll get an empty array. If you do `var sub = Meteor.subscribe('sitelist');` then you can look at `sub.ready()` to know that the subscription is *ready* - meaning the data has been transferred from server to client.

Answer (score 0):

It is logging `[]` because the subscription is not yet ready. To figure out when the subscription is ready you have to pass it a callback function. Then in your callback execute code that is dependent on the subscription.

```
$meteor.subscribe('sitelist', function(error, result) {
  console.log(result.fetch());
});
```